# How to namespace caches by environment using config.cache_store = :redis_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I have set up Rails to use redis as its cache store:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store
```

However, I have a staging environment on the same server as production and they both use the same redis instance.

How can I namespace the redis cache records by environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to initializers/session_store.rb

**YourApp::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, servers: { namespace: 'sessions' }**

Answer (score 2):

`redis-store` gem can accept namespace as the second parameter for session store. Maybe it also can accept namespace for cache store the same way?

[Rails Configuration](https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store/wiki/Frameworks-Configuration)